# My absolute positioned element pushes my content aside

Tags: html, css, absolute

I don't really get why this happens, my parent is positioned relative, here's a simplified version of the code, if u delete the absolute positioned div the other divs spread out like they should.

```css
[type="row"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px !important;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
}
[type*="row"][type*="drag"] {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
[type*="drag"] {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 100;
  cursor: move;
}
[type="col"] {
  border: 1px dotted green;
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
}
[type="cell"] {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div type="row">
    <div type="row drag"></div>
    <div style="width: 33.3%" type="col">
      <div type="cell">Test1</div>
    </div>

    <div style="width: 33.4%;" type="col">
      <div type="cell">Test2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

EDIT: If you set the display of the absolute div to none it will stretch out the other 2 cells, this is the behavior i need. It's party of a drag and drop jquery story

Comment: Your html is invalid. There is no `type` attribute on the `div` element. Why are you not using `class`? Also, `header` must be a child of `body`. Probably you mean `head`.

Comment: You fail to understand my answer, yet you keep downvoting the answers that people gave you. Good luck then.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use `position: absolute;` inside a table. This includes containers that have `display: table;` as your outer container `<div type="row">` has.

Apart from that, your html is **invalid**. There is no `type` attribute on the `div` element. Why are you not using `class`?

Also, `header` must be a child of `body`. Probably you mean `head`.

Comment: I never typed header.. Also I see "type" all over the place

Comment: and i need it to be type, it's all part of a bigger jquery story

Comment: No matter what you need, it's still invalid. And you did type `header`. It's gone now since I edited your post.